# How to make HTML changes or customize module like poll in BigBlueButton html5-client?

Tags: meteor, client, ubuntu-18.04, bigbluebutton

I'm using bigbluebutton (2.3-dev) in Ubuntu 18.04 server I installed it using bbb-install `(# wget -qO- https://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bbb-install.sh | bash -s -- -v bionic-230-dev -s bbb.example.com -e info@example.com -a -w)` and its work perfect.
Now I want to make some changes in html5-client `(https://doamin/html5client/join?sessionToken=e)`
I found the file path - `/usr/share/meteor/bundle` and it's served from this path `/usr/share/meteor/bundle/programs/web.browser` but problem is this is a build file so I can't make any changes because every time this file is new generator when stop and start or restart.

I want to add one link in left side menu (http://prntscr.com/umy63l). How can I do this and where I can do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install a dev environement for bbb-html5 ? You can find the doc about it here :
https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/2.2/dev.html#developing-the-html5-client

Comment: Thank you for this answer but I found a solution and completed my customize.

Comment: Yes, I Followed this same document

Comment: can you please share solution, what did do because the link is broken